# Pattern match if not nil

Tags: swift

```
# Let's say I've got the following typealias
public typealias DateRange = (from: NSDate?, to: NSDate?)

# And use it here
var selectedDateRange: DateRange = (nil, nil)
```

Can I then use pattern matching to both get the values and unwrap it using pattern matching?

```
# I can check vs. `nil` like so:

if case (nil, nil) = segmentControl.selectedCustomDateRange {
    print("Damn, nil!")
}

# And I want something shorter than
if let from = segmentControl.selectedDateRange.from,
   let to = segmentControl.selectedDateRange.to
{
    model.setPeriod(from, to: to)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if` with pattern matching and the optional pattern
`x?`:

```
if case let (from?, to?) = selectedDateRange {
    model.setPeriod(from, to: to)
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I did try variations, like `(from: NSDate?, to: NSDate?)`, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the above, but different...

```
guard case let (from?, to?) = selectedDateRange else {
    print("Damn, at least one nil!")
    return
}
model.setPeriod(from, to: to)}
```

Comment: Thanks this as well. Different situations calls for different solutions and sometimes guards are preferred.